# Remove or replace copyright in magento

Tags: php, magento, magento-1.9

As i know: to remove or replace the copyright in magento we need to do:
"Go to System > Configuration" and change copyright.
or open file `template/page/footer.phtml` remove

```
<?php echo $this->getCopyright() ?>
```

My purpose is replace `getCopyright()` by my function to show the other content with my custom module. Can anyone help me?

Comment: Have you tried opening `template/page/footer.phtml`, removing `$this->getCopyright()` and replacing it with your function from a custom module?

Comment: thanks Robbie Averill,
i don't want to make this way.

Answer (score 1):

The 'getCopyright' method is defined in the 'Mage_Page_Block_Html_Footer' class. Your extension should override this class. The other way is replace this block with block from your extension.

The declaration of the block override in the config.xml should look like:

```
<?xml version="1.0"?> 
<config>
    ...
    <global>
        <blocks>
            <page>
                <rewrite>
                     <html_footer>Novaweb_Novawebaddons_Block_Copyright</html_footer>
                </rewrite>
            </page>
        </blocks>
        <cms>
            <page>
                <tempate_filter>Novaweb_Novawebaddons_Model_Filter</tempate_filter>
            </page>
            <block>
                <tempate_filter>Novaweb_Novawebaddons_Model_Filter</tempate_filter>
            </block>
        </cms>
    </global>
    ...
</config>
```

'Novaweb/Novawebaddons/Model/Filter.php' file:

```
<?php
class Novaweb_Novawebaddons_Model_Filter extends Mage_Cms_Model_Template_Filter
{
    public function configDirective($construction)
    {
        $params = $this->_getIncludeParameters($construction[2]);
        if (!empty($params['path']) && ($params['path'] == 'design/footer/copyright'))
            return 'My copyright';

        return parent::configDirective($construction);
    }
}
```

Comment: Hi Neodan
My code:
config.xml
 <page>
         <rewrite>
                <html_footer>Novaweb_Novawebaddons_Block_Copyright</html_footer> 
         </rewrite>
     </page>  
file  copyright.php
<?php

class Novaweb_Novawebaddons_Block_Copyright extends Mage_Page_Block_Html_Footer
{
    public function getCopyright()
    {
       
        return 'My copyright';
    }

}
 //
function getCopyright not working,i have been trying create the function __construct() in the copyright.php file and  it work well
i don't know why

Comment: I updated the answer. Check if your override is correctly declared. For me it works.

Comment: thanks Neodan,i dont know what happen with my source code
i copy my source code to the new source code magento. it's work well. but the current source code is not working.
thank you for your help.

Comment: Did you tried to flush the Magento cache storage? Because the problem can be in the cache.

Comment: the customer uses "{{config path="design/footer/copyright"}}" in static block. i dont know what is the best way to replace the copyright if customer uses cofig patch in magento
thanks Neodan

Comment: Then you need to override/extend the 'configDirective' method (`class Mage_Core_Model_Email_Template_Filter`).

Comment: I updated my answer (added override for 'config' directive)